# Как сделать чтобы бот читал (произносил) каждую букву из списка

Tags: python, бот

Новичок делаю бота на python. Я пытаюсь сделать чтобы бот отвечал на то что я говорю, по шаблону и молча он отвечает, но я не могу понять как сделать чтобы он читал (произносил) каждую букву из списка. И чтобы код был не огромный (у меня как раз так). Если что бота я пишу не для твиттера, вк и т. д. А просто для себя

```
import pygame.mixer, time
  a=1
while a == 1:
  say = input('')
  l=list(''.join(say))
```

Comment: Если код не огромный (15-20 строк) приведите его прямо в своём вопросе (дополнить можно кнопкой [edit]), если кода больше, создайте [mcve].

Comment: `как сделать чтобы он читал (произносил) каждую букву из списка` — надо чтобы каждую букву отдельно, или всё таки чтобы читал слова?

Comment: А погуглить ? http://pythono.ru/tts-python/

Comment: @diraria что бы из звуков слова получались. Получается что да "что бы читал слова", но у меня почти получилось.

Comment: @IndiGuy подумайте: [a]дна буква м[o]жет [a]б[a]значать разные звуки. Нужно учесть твердые и [м'ях'к'ийэ] согласные, оглушение согласных в конце слова, сочетания букв, ударéния, интонация...  Чтение слов не сводится к «чтению букв», а произнесение предложений — к чтению слов.

Answer (score 1):

Преобразование текста в речь является, вообще говоря, нетривиальной задачей. Существуют готовые реализации, которые можно разделить на две группы:

- Онлайн сервисы, в которых реализована такая возможность, например Google.Переводчик или Яндекс.Переводчик
- Локальные программы для разных ОС

Онлайн сервисов существует множество и локальных программ тоже существует множество. К некоторым из них написаны обёртки — python модули, которые, работают с api сервисов/программ. Например, [вот неполный список python-модулей](https://github.com/search?l=Python&o=desc&q=google+tts&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93), преобразовывающих текст в речь, используя Google.Переводчик.

Наиболее простым и удобным из них выглядит [gTTS](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS), рассмотрим пример программы на нём:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import pygame

# инициализируем gTTS, одним из способов:
tts = gTTS(text='Привет, мир', lang='ru')  # русский текст
tts = gTTS(text='Hello world', lang='en')  # английский текст
tts = gTTS(text='Hello world', lang='en', slow=True)  # английский текст, медленное произношение

# преобразуем текст в речь, используя google-переводчик
# и сохраняем получившеюся речь в mp3 файл
tts.save('text.mp3')

# инициализация pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()

# загружаем речь из mp3 файла
pygame.mixer.music.load('text.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()

# music.play() — неблокирующий метод
# код ниже будет ждать, пока речь закончит произносится
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(pygame.USEREVENT)
pygame.event.wait()
```

Эта программа получает речь используя google-переводчик, сохраняет её в mp3 файл, затем с помощью `pygame` проигрывает этот mp3 файл. Можно обойтись без mp3 файла, используя in-memory бинарный поток (`io.BytesIO`):

```
from gtts import gTTS
import pygame
import io

tts = gTTS(text='Привет, мир', lang='ru')

with io.BytesIO() as f:
    tts.write_to_fp(f)
    f.seek(0)

    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.init()

    pygame.mixer.music.load(f)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

    pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(pygame.USEREVENT)
    pygame.event.wait()
```

Comment: спасибо) я уже решил задачу, просто записал каждую букву своим голосом ускорил и убрал пробелы до и после звука буквы. А воспроизвожу звуки с помощью pygame.

Comment: ты не мог бы подсказать(просто 2 вопроса в день) смотри у меня есть код                                                                                         `filename = 'dial.txt'
fine = open(filename, mode ="r", encoding = 'utf-8')
for line in fine:
    if x in line:
        print(line)` мне нужно что бы вывелась строка после найденной, как это сделать скажи пожалуйста

Comment: @IndiGuy да, считай сначала весь файл в массив строк: `lines = open(...).readlines()`, а затем итерируйся по этому массиву строк используя индексы: `for i in range(len(lines)): if x in lines[i]: print(lines[i+1])`

Comment: Спасибо огромное)